# Linking SDL2 in QtCreator

Tags: c++, macos, qt, sdl, qmake

So I want to use Qt as an editor for my SDL app. When I try to make even just a blank project in Qt and link up the libraries, it just can't find SDL2/SDL.h. Here is whats inside my .pro file:

```
mac: LIBS += "-F$$PWD/../Control Libraries/" -framework SDL2
INCLUDEPATH += "$$PWD/../Control Libraries/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/Headers"


mac: LIBS += "-F$$PWD/../Control Libraries/" -framework SDL2_mixer
INCLUDEPATH += "$$PWD/../Control Libraries/SDL2_mixer.framework/Versions/A/Headers"


mac: LIBS += "-F$$PWD/../Control Libraries/" -framework SDL2_ttf
INCLUDEPATH += "$$PWD/../Control Libraries/SDL2_ttf.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```

I can't find anyone who has posted how to get this to work, but I know there has to be some way. It works in Xcode with one click, so am I just doing something wrong? Thanks.

EDIT:

Here iss the error message:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I../SpudEngineEditor -I../Control\ Libraries/SDL2.framework/Headers -I../Control\ Libraries/SDL2_mixer.framework/Headers -I../Control\ Libraries/SDL2_ttf.framework/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/Logan/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib -o Camera.o ../SpudEngineEditor/Camera.cpp
In file included from ../SpudEngineEditor/Camera.cpp:9:
In file included from ../SpudEngineEditor/Camera.h:13:
../SpudEngineEditor/CoreEngine.h:14:9: warning: unknown pragma ignored [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")
        ^
In file included from ../SpudEngineEditor/Camera.cpp:9:
In file included from ../SpudEngineEditor/Camera.h:13:
In file included from ../SpudEngineEditor/CoreEngine.h:34:
../Control Libraries/SDL2_ttf.framework/Headers/SDL_ttf.h:30:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

EDIT: I've gotten it so I can include , but not , which is a problem because SDL mixer and SDL rtf both use

Comment: Some clarification: Qt Creator is just an IDE. It's commonly installed with Qt SDK, and is most often used to develop Qt applications. But it's still a separate thing from Qt (SDK or libraries).

Comment: @hyde I am planning to use the QT SDK for the project, I just need to figure out how to link the libraries first.

Comment: In a question like this, it's usually a good idea to show the exact failing compile command (look for it in the compile output view of Qt Creator). If my answer does not solve this, then you could add this to the question.

Comment: Can you see the *compile command*? For *gcc* it would be `gcc ... -I ... -c ... main.cpp` something, presumably about same for *clang*.

Comment: @hyde Updated the question to include that.

Comment: Edited my answer about something else, if that does not fix the issue (and you are sure you remembered to put the `""` everywhere they are needed in `.pro` file, then next step would be to open Qt command prompt (however you do that in Mac, so that you have compilers in PATH), go to the directory where that command is run (it should be visible in compile output). Then you can try copy-pasting the command by hand, and can verify that all relative paths in the command are correct, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You should use double quotes when paths have spaces in them, for example:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "$$PWD/../Control Libraries/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```

Unless you do want them to be separate arguments, for example:

```
mac: LIBS += "-F$$PWD/../Control Libraries/" -framework SDL2_mixer
```

---

After question edit: So you have `#include <SDL2/SDl.h>`. It seems to have wrong case, should probably be

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I've included the complete error in the question.

Comment: That let me include <SDL.h> not <SDL2/SDL.h> which is a problem, as SDL mixer and SDL ttf both try to use SDL2/SDL.h. I've updated the question  to reflect the new changes.

Comment: @BlueSpud What is the full absolute path to that `SDL.h`?

Comment: @BlueSpud I know I'm 2 years too late, but just in case this is useful to someone: The reason for this is that the header files are contained directly in Headers in the framework directory. You could manually create an SDL2 directory inside Headers and move all of the .h files in there... Doesn't seem ideal, but it certainly works.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is clear about the error:

> ../SpudEngineEditor/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDl.h' file not found

What you ought to do is to replace this line:

```
#include <SDL2/SDl.h>
```

with:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
//               ^, yes uppercase.
```

Also, as for the paths with whitespaces, you ought to use for instance [the corresponding quote qmake function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#quote-string) established for this purpose, which will also work with double quotes inside. Double quotes might work, too, in all cases, but I personally prefer the fancy function if there is one established. :-)

I would also establish an auxilliary variable if I were you not to repeat the same path a couple of times.

Furthermore, I would write a qmake function, although that is not necessary with inline calls, that uses the real qmake power, the for loop since you are repeating the same thing. Thereby, I would be writing something like this:

```
setSDLPaths() {
    CONTROL_LIBRARIES_PATH = $$quote($$PWD/../Control Libraries/)
    LIST = SDL2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_mixer
    for(item, LIST) {
        mac: LIBS += -F$$CONTROL_LIBRARIES_PATH -framework $$item
        INCLUDEPATH += $$CONTROL_LIBRARIES_PATH/$${item}.framework/Versions/A/Headers
    }
}
```

which then would simplify your code a lot, basically to a one-liner:

```
$$setSDLPaths()
```

Comment: Where would I put this function? Just changing the name didn't actually work, and putting this in the .pro file also didn't work.

Comment: @BlueSpud: [does not work](http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/05/doesnt-work-doesnt-work/) does not work.